# handle exception thrown from constructors in JSF using Handlers

Tags: jsf-2, exception

Hello folks,
            Though this is my first question, Iam used to reading solutions in stackoverflow and am really pleased to get appropriate answers.

My question is : Is there any way to handle exception thrown from a constructor using some handlers (Instead of writing try and catch in every constructor) and redirect page to an error.xhtml. Iam using JSF2. And how i can identify the exception is thrown from constructor.
Waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, try to avoid doing anything in the constructor of a managed bean, it's unnecessary and ugly. Annotate a public, no-argument method with the `@PostConstruct` annotation and that method is guaranteed to run immediately after the managed bean has been instantiated.

To address your main issue, JSF provides an `ExceptionHandler` class that you can override for the benefit of custom exception handling. It's implemented in a semi-declarative way and applies globally, i.e. for the entire JSF application context. This [tutorial](http://javalabor.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/jsf-2-global-exception-handling.html) provides a good guide on implementing the handler. From that tutorial, note that the `ExceptionQueuedEvent` object provides all the information available concerning the exception thrown including the JSF Phase in which the exception was thrown and even the component that generated the exception

Comment: @arunsankarkk, you're welcome. Please don't forget to mark this answer as accepted. See [how voting works here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)